# My assest studio is showing this messagse I cannot search for new icons

Tags: android, android-studio

[It's Randomnly Stopped WOrkin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyQil.png)

^Link to image

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Please update your android studio to upgrade version. It will fix your issue or change drop down **filled** with other options.